# how to get the date separated in SQL 2008 Server

Tags: sql-server, xquery

Hi i have the following query which gives me the result of my desired and except one thing.

MyQuery :

```
(SELECT
    (SELECT
        '3'       as '@CategoryDepth',
        'CIMtrek_SelectedPage' as '@SelectedPage',
        'CIMtrek_ParentID'     as '@ParentID',
        'CIMtrek_LstParm'      as '@LstParm',
        'CIMtrek_SearchParm'   as '@SearchParm',
        'CIMtrek_Search_No'    as '@isSearch',
        'CIMtrek_CDS1'     as '@ViewName'
        FOR XML PATH('AppConfig'), TYPE ),
        (SELECT
        RES.Header as '@Header'
        FROM (
         SELECT 'Date' AS Header
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'MY MENU' AS Header
        ) AS RES

        FOR XML PATH('ColumnHeader'), TYPE ),

        (SELECT
        RES.Param as '@Param'
        FROM (
         SELECT 'CIMtrek_daily_shipdate' AS Param
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'MY PARM' AS Param
        ) AS RES

        FOR XML PATH('Params'), TYPE ),
        (SELECT
        RES.Search as '@Search'
        FROM (
         SELECT 'Date|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Department|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_PackingMethod] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Rush|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_Rush] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Customer Name|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_CustomerName_1] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Schedule Name|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_schedule_name] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Carrier|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_carrier] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Order|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_order] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Load #|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_load] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Pieces|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_pieces] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Cases|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_cases] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Weight|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_weight] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'Cube|[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_cube] ' AS Search
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'MY SEARCH|Search' AS Search
        ) AS RES

        FOR XML PATH('Search'), TYPE ),
        (SELECT
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT
         ISNULL([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],'')  AS CIMtrek_daily_shipdate

        FROM
            [CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse] [T1] WHERE  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate])),'')))) != 0  AND 
 1 = 1
            AND [T1].[CIMtrek_form] in ('Compliance Daily Shipments') 
            AND [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_status] not in ('Complete')
            AND [T1].[CIMtrek_Archive] not in ('Archived')
        GROUP BY
         ISNULL([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],'') 

        ) AS COUNTS1
        ) AS '@CIMtrek_COUNT' ,
        '1' AS '@CIMtrek_COUNT_Level',
        (SELECT
        [T1].[ROW] AS '@Row'
        ,newid() AS '@UnqCimID'
        <!-- 
            changed this to format date to be DD/MM/YYYY

         , [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate] AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'

           -->
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],106) AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'

        FROM (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  ISNULL([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],'') 
 ASC) ROW
        , ISNULL([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],'')  AS CIMtrek_daily_shipdate

        FROM
        [CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse] [T1]  WHERE  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate])),'')))) != 0  AND 
 1 = 1
            AND [T1].[CIMtrek_form] in ('Compliance Daily Shipments') 
            AND [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_status] not in ('Complete')
            AND [T1].[CIMtrek_Archive] not in ('Archived')
        GROUP BY
         ISNULL([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],'') 
) T1
        WHERE [T1].ROW BETWEEN 1 and 10
        order by convert(date,[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],103)
        FOR XML PATH('Data'), TYPE
        )FOR XML PATH('Data'), TYPE) )FOR XML PATH('Root')
```

in the above query i have commented the below line:

```
<!-- 
            changed this to format date to be DD/MM/YYYY

         , [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate] AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'

           -->
```

and put the following line

```
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],106) AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'
```

This converts the date which is like : `01-Nov-12 12:00:00 AM` to `01-Nov-12` and it is also fine but in some cases i get the date `01-Nov-12 12:45:21 AM` in this case i have to show the date and time.

so practically i should not show when the date time is  `01-Nov-12 12:00:00 AM`  and show when the date time is `01-Nov-12 12:45:21 AM`.

How to handle this in query itself?

Kindly help me to get this.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtracting the Date portion you can determine if the DateTime column actually contains a Time Element and can then format appropriately, E.g...

```
Case When [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate]-Convert(Date,[T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate]) = 0
     Then Convert(varchar(12), [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate], 113)
     Else Convert(varchar(20), [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate], 113)
     End AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'
```

I've used date format 113 which gives me the format `12 Dec 2012 13:43:44` but any other date format which includes a time element will work, simply change the `Convert()` function call.

This assumes that the source column is a DateTime and that you can subtract the date portion from the DateTime column as shown. In the event that the source column is a varchar then you can simply remove any unwanted time elements by replacing the unwanted string with an empty string. E.g.

```
REPLACE([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],' 12:00:00 AM','') AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'
```

Assuming the time is actually formatted in this manner. You can also nest `REPLACE()` functions, E.g.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],' 12:00:00 AM',''),' 12:00 AM','') AS '@CIMtrek_daily_shipdate'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i get this `Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 87
Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for subtract operator.` when i run the query with the changes you have given

Comment: Really? It worked fine on my db. What's the data type of [T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate] ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is varchar

Comment: Ah. lol, I thought it was a DateTime because you used a Convert() on it in your code. Silly me, never assume. In that case then simply use REPLACE([T1].[CIMtrek_daily_shipdate],'12:00:00 AM','') or something similar to get rid of the time bit you don't want.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this, can you Edit your answer with this as your  will help trainee like me. `Thanks a lot' it resolve my issue.